# Android Chrome Custom Tabs - Open link in new tab + Postmessage

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, postmessage, chrome-custom-tabs

I've got two web pages. The first one opens the second one in a new tab. They're talking to each other with JavaScript's postMessage. This setup works fine in every browser (desktop/mobile).

When I try to simulate the same behavior using Chrome Custom Tabs on Android the second page is opened in the same layout instead in a new one. As a result I can no longer use postMessage.

How to force **links inside a custom tab to be opened in a new custom tab** and preserve postMessage capabilities?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to create another custom tab from web contents. This is because we want to maintain a quick way to return to the app that opened the tab.

On the other hand, I cannot recall the logic checking for tab type/visibility in postMessage. Sounds like a bug.

A bug with detailed reproducer would help a lot, please use the "this template" link in README.md: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/custom-tabs-client

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Egor, thanks for your help!

The problem has been solved by installing the **newest version of Chrome** for Android.

Using Chrome Custom Tabs with Chrome 48.0.2564.95 *window2* loads its content into *window1*. As of Chrome 49.0.2623.91, *window1*'s state is preserved and *window2* opens on top in the same custom tab, thus hiding *window1*. The postMessage works just fine. You can see the attached screenshot.

[Android Chrome Debugging with Inspect Devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrjxU.png)

However, a minor bug is still present. When alert is fired from bottom page *window1*, *window2* becomes inactive, but remains visible. That means the focus is on *window1*, but you see *window2*'s content. I have to move the focus back to *window2* manually using the debugger to restore the proper working setup.